# Cant seem to import specific module in Python

Tags: python

I have installed TextBlob.

```
$ python -m pip install TextBlob
Requirement already satisfied: TextBlob in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: nltk>=3.1 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from   TextBlob)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from    nltk>=3.1->TextBlob)
```

Only now when I try to run this code:

```
from __future__ import division, unicode_literals

import math
from textblob import TextBlob as tb

def tf(word, blob):
 return blob.words.count(word) / len(blob.words)

def n_containing(word, bloblist):
 return sum(1 for blob in bloblist if word in blob.words)

def idf(word, bloblist):
 return math.log(len(bloblist) / (1 + n_containing(word, bloblist)))

def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
 return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)
```

I still get this error:

```
   from textblob import TextBlob as tb
ImportError: No module named 'textblob'
```

Any thoughts on what is going wrong here?

Comment: You installed `TextBlob`, _not_ `textblob`, right?

Comment: @ForceBru, textblob gives me the same....

Comment: What returns just `python -c 'import textblob'`?

Comment: unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ForceBru: the import is not at fault, see the [project documentation](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/).

Comment: This issue is commonly caused by not using the same Python binary. Check that `import sys; print(sys.executable)` points to the same Python interpreter.

Comment: What @MartijnPieters said, you might have installed the package for a different version of python. You can open cmd and type `python --version` to see the default version in the PATH.