# Incorrect module path in Python

Tags: python

I recently had a problem with importing a python and therefore posted this question: [Cant seem to import specific module in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637590/cant-seem-to-import-specific-module-in-python?noredirect=1#comment70477128_41637590)

Based on input I got I did some digging and saw the following:

If I open cygwin and input  python --version, I get this

```
Marc@Marc ~
$ python --version
 Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)
```

And if I open python using myCharm and input this:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

I get:

```
 C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Marc/PycharmProjects/clustering/testing.py
C:\Users\Marc\PycharmProjects\clustering
C:\Users\Marc\PycharmProjects\clustering
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\python35.zip
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\DLLs
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\lib
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.4.6-py3.5.egg
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib 
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg
```

So assume this highlights the problem. Could anybody tell me what is wise to do here? Change the path in my terminal of change the path in python

Comment: What would you like to see, whta do you expect? Is the problem that Cygwin uses Python 2.7 and Anaconda uses Python 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

If you set an envirnment variable called `PYTHONPATH` to a colon-separated (Windows: semicolon-separated) list of directories, each of them will be added to the interpreter's `sys.path`. This is the recommended way of making modules available.

So for example, let's suppose you had added Python modules in the directory `C:\Documents and Settings\frits\private`. Before you run your Python program you would execute the command

```
SET PYTHONPATH=C:\Documents and Settings\frits\private
```

No semicolon is required in this case because there's only one directory.

The when you run Python you will find that your `sys.path` has another entry corresponding to the `C:\Documents and Settings\frits\private` directory.

In the longer term, to avoid conflicts between the requirements of different projects (e.g. you want to run two programs that require a different version of the same third-party module) you should investigate the use of virtual environments.

Comment: thanks but I dont understand what you mean. Could you please elaborate?